# Camera Launcher not working Cordova 2.9

Tags: camera, phonegap-plugins

I want to create a simple "take a photo" Android application with **Cordova 2.9** with a single button launching the getPicture() API , but **nothing happens when I click on the button I created**.
Here is the code of my index.html file in www folder :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Take a photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener(“deviceready”,onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoSuccess(imageData) {
    var myImage = document.getElementById(‘myImage’);
    myImage.style.display = ‘block’;
    myImage.src = “data:image/jpeg;base64,” + imageData;}

    function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoSuccess, onPhotoFail, { quality: 50 });
    }

    function onPhotoFail(message) {
    alert(‘Failed because: ‘ + message);
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick=”capturePhoto();”>Capture Photo</button> <br>
        <img style=”display:none;width:60px;height:60px;” id=”myImage” src=”” />
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my config.xml file :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.localdb.com" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Localdb</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml  file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.localdb.com" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Can you please tell if anything is missing in my files thank you in advance !

Comment: did you add camera plugins in your project

Comment: Yes I did, my app folder contains a plugins folder with all the plugins I installed through command lines.. I really don't know what's wrong